# Implement build configurations in Java/Android under Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, build, conditional-compilation, buildconfiguration

I'm a C programmer doing some Android development using Eclipse and my application needs to have several different variations for "private labeling" for different companies. These variations will have different strings on the GUI, different backgrounds for the home screen (containing the companies logo for each of the different companies), different app icons, different app names, etc.

So far every time I've released an update I've gone through and manually changed each of these things in the code and resource files to build a custom apk for each of the multiple companies we are providing the "branded" app for... which is a pain in the ass and fraught with potential error.

In C I would just set up build configurations with different predefines and trigger code in or out based on the predefined values. Then I can just switch the configuration, build the project, switch to the next configuration, build the project, etc.

There has to be a way to do this with Eclipse... please tell me there is!

Comment: Properties file might be a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven to build your project, [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) feature is what you need.

Comment: I'm not, just using eclipse, but I'll look into it, thanks.